# Is it possible to store multiple key value pair array in google app engine?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, web

I am Using python and google app engine. I have a list of images and I would like to store an external page link to each image. so right now in Google app engine the images are stored like:

```
contentimages:  image1,image2,image3,image4.
```

I would like to put the enternal link like this:

```
contentimages: [{image1,link},{image2,link},{image3,link}]
```

how can I achieve this? Quiet new to python and google app engine. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could probably use the ndb [PickleProperty](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/entity-property-reference) for this.  The PickleProperty let's you store arbitrary Python data structures.

You could store the data as a list of tuples:

```
contentimages = [(image1, link1), (image2, link2), (image3, link3)]
```

Or as a list of dicts:

```
contentimages = [{img: image1, lnk:link1}, {img: image2, lnk: link2},{img: image3, lnk:link3}]
```

Comment: alternatively, use `JSONProperty`

Comment: Thxx @Jeff O'Neil.